# Celery Beat: Task is in celery.conf_schedule but doesn't run or appear in beat worker logs

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm running celery v4.0.2, rabbitmq 3.6.10 and flask.

The following code builds my Celery object.

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://', include=['jobs'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


logger.init_logger(console=True, log_dir=False, verbose=False)

logger.info('Starting Application')
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
celery = make_celery(app)
```

I'm then adding a task to the beat schedule using the following,

```
celery.add_periodic_task(10.0, APP.jobs.ex.s())
print celery.conf.beat_schedule

>> {'APP.jobs.ex()': {u'kwargs': {}, u'task': u'APP.jobs.ex', u'options': {}, u'args': (), u'schedule': 10.0}}
```

I'm running a worker here and this works fine for adding normal tasks,

```
celery -A APP.celery worker -l info
```

I'm running a beat scheduler here,

```
celery -A APP.celery beat -l info

>> celery beat v4.0.2 (latentcall) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2017-07-27 16:31:16
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2017-07-27 16:31:16,320: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

However, from this point nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Is 10 suppose to be seconds? Whatever it is, you could change it to a timedelta of that interval. Or crontab if it is something more cron-based. I haven't used just an integer before.

Comment: Yes, integers are used in the examples in the documentation. It turns out I'm not able to add periodic tasks to the object if they're not defined in the same file as the initial object. Doesn't make much sense to me - but at least it's working.